# Entity Framework -- An item with the same key has already been added

Tags: entity-framework-5

I am having an intermittent error that I am not able to figure out.  When my application is starting up the following line gives me the error stated in the title.

```
IList<DataAgentStatus> list = dbContext.DataAgentStatus.ToList();
```

The "DataAgentStatus" table only has 12 rows in it and the primary key is a string with unique names in it.

Any thoughts or ideas on where I should look?  Most times if I hit "Continue" the application runs fine.

DataAgentStatus class  (NotificationObject is a prism object that implements INotifyPropertyChanged)

```
public class DataAgentStatus : NotificationObject
{
    [Key]
    public string DataAgentName { get; set; }

    public DateTime? LastAccessDate { get; set; }
    public bool ErrorState { get; set; }
    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
    public int? Quantity { get; set; }

    public DateTime? CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? LastModifiedDate { get; set; }

    [Timestamp]
    public byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Entry on the DbContext class

```
public DbSet<DataAgentStatus> DataAgentStatus { get; set; }
```

Call Stack from error.

> at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add)
>     at System.Data.Objects.ObjectStateManager.AddEntityEntryToDictionary(EntityEntry entry, EntityState state)
>      at System.Data.Objects.ObjectStateManager.AddEntry(IEntityWrapper wrappedObject, EntityKey passedKey, EntitySet entitySet, String argumentName, Boolean isAdded)
>      at System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper.HandleEntityAppendOnly[TEntity](Func`2 constructEntityDelegate, EntityKey entityKey, EntitySet entitySet)
>      at lambda_method(Closure , Shaper )
>      at System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.Coordinator`1.ReadNextElement(Shaper shaper)
>      at System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper`1.SimpleEnumerator.MoveNext()
>      at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
>      at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
>      at WPF.Data.Models.DataAgentStatus.List(DataBroker dbContext) in c:\Projects\WPF - Trunk\src\Components\Framework.WPF\Data\Models\DataAgentStatus.cs:line 88
>      at Framework.WPF.Data.Models.DataAgentStatus.ReloadObjects(DataBroker dbContext) in c:\Projects\WPF - Trunk\src\Components\Framework.WPF\Data\Models\DataAgentStatus.cs:line 101
>      at WPF.Data.Models.DataAgentStatus.LoadByType(DataBroker dbContext, String statusName, Boolean forceReload) in c:\Projects\WPF - Trunk\src\Components\Framework.WPF\Data\Models\DataAgentStatus.cs:line 73
>      at Framework.WPF.Data.Models.DataAgentStatus.LoadByType(DataBroker dbContext, String statusName) in c:\Projects\WPF - Trunk\src\Components\Framework.WPF\Data\Models\DataAgentStatus.cs:line 66
>      at Base.Data.Handlers.ReferenceDataHandler.GetUserWebLinks(ReceivingDatabroker dbContext) in c:\Projects\WPF - Trunk\src\Receiving\Receiving.Base\Data\Handlers\ReferenceDataHandler.cs:line 40
>      at Base.Data.Agents.UserWebLinkDataAgent.UserLinks(ReceivingDatabroker dbContext) in c:\Projects\WPF - Trunk\src\Receiving\Receiving.Base\Data\Agents\UserWebLinkDataAgent.cs:line 41
>      at Receiving.Base.Data.Handlers.LoginHandler.timmy_Elapsed(Object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e) in c:\Projects\WPF - Trunk\src\Receiving\Receiving.Base\Data\Handlers\LoginHandler.cs:line 144
>      at System.Timers.Timer.MyTimerCallback(Object state)

Comment: Its most likely happening outside of this line. Are you using any kind of DI framework?

Comment: No.  This is the line that .Net stops on.  When it happens again, I will post the stack trace also (forgot to grab then when I got the error last time)

Comment: Can you show the `DataAgentStatus` class and possible mapping with Fluent API for this class?

Comment: Updated the original message to have the DataAgentStatus Class and the DbSet line